# Setting animation for Bend4Web with curve extruding

Tags: animation, blend4web

[image: result in blend4web]

Hello, I am trying to export the animation I done with mesh extruding along curve  in Blend4Web, actually I have set all the object element to export shape keys as I thought this was the problem but it wont work.

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong here please?
Thank you very much for your time

Comment: i am very sorry i cant figure out how to add other images in the forum to whow you the scene set up ans the node tree i have made; i started blender one week  ago almost and i am not very familiar with htmal or programing thank you for helping me

Comment: I don't think you can export curve animations, and these are not shapekeys. Anyway, you'd better ask this at [their forum](https://www.blend4web.com/forums/).